# Update ViewModel from View with an attached property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to save/load column orders on a `DataGrid`. I'm trying to bind a `StringCollection` that contains `DataGrid` column indexes between my ViewModel and View. I can successfully set the `StringCollection` in my ViewModel that updates the View using attached properties but when I change the column orders in my View using the UI then the ViewModel is not updated to reflect the new column orders. How can I get my ViewModel to listen to the View's changes?

My xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"
          attach:DataGridColumnChanger.ColumnOrder="{Binding ColumnOrders, Mode=TwoWay}">
</DataGrid>
```

My attached property

```
public class DataGridColumnChanger : DependencyObject
{
   #region dependency properties
   public static StringCollection GetColumnOrder(DependencyObject obj)
   {
      return (StringCollection)obj.GetValue(ColumnOrderProperty);
   }
   public static void SetColumnOrder(DependencyObject obj, StringCollection value)
   {
      obj.SetValue(ColumnOrderProperty, value);
   }
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnOrderProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnOrder",
      typeof(StringCollection), typeof(DataGridColumnChanger), new UIPropertyMetadata(new StringCollection(), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnColumnOrderChange)));

   #endregion

   private static void OnColumnOrderChange(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      var element = obj as DataGrid;
      if (element != null)
      {
         try
         {
            StringCollection collection = (StringCollection)e.NewValue;
            if (collection != null && collection.Count > 0)
            {
               for (int j = 0; j <= element.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
               {
                  int index = Convert.ToInt32(collection[j]);
                  element.Columns[j].DisplayIndex = index;
               }
            }
         }
         catch
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My ViewModel

```
private StringCollection columnOrders = new StringCollection();
public System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection ColumnOrders
{
   get => this.columnOrders;
   set
   {
      this.columnOrders = value;
      this.RaisePropertyChanged("ColumnOrders");
   }
}
```

Comment: You should at some point in your attached property code subscribe to your `DataGrid` changes and call `SetColumnOrder ` accordingly. How could your binding know there was a change in you never change the value from the attached property?

Comment: How would that look? Do you mean like listen out for an event such as ColumnDisplayIndexChanged in the attached property class and call SetColumnOrder in that?

Comment: yes exactly, that should be about it

Comment: @chris What do you want to do in this case, update the existing collection or create a new collection each time? Another question is, how do you initialize the collection, the code does only work if either the string collection is empty or has items _for all_ columns. Speaking of the collection, why do you use a `StringCollection`, when the display indices are `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attached behavior must listen to the attached `DataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged` event. Handle this events and synchronize the source collection of the attached `DataGrid`:

```
private static ConditionalWeakTable<DataGrid, DataGrid> RegisteredInstances { get; } = new ConditionalWeakTable<DataGrid, DataGrid>();

private static void OnColumnOrderChange(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (element is DataGrid dataDrid)
  {
    if (!RegisteredInstances.TryGetValue(dataDrid, out _))
    {
      RegisteredInstances.Add(dataDrid, dataDrid);
      dataDrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += OnDataGridColumnOrderChanged;
    }

    try
    {
      ...
    }
    catch
    {
      ...
    }              
  }
}

private static void OnDataGridColumnOrderChanged(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
  if (RegisteredInstances.TryGetValue(dataDrid, out _))
  {
    StringCollection newColumnOrderCollection = new StringCollection();

    // TODO::Populate newColumnOrderCollection using e.Column.DisplayIndex 
    // and raise property changed by assigning the collection to the OrderCollection property
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attached property implemetation only reacts on changes to the collection. In order to react to changes in the user interface you have to subscribe to the [`DataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columndisplayindexchanged?view=net-5.0) event.

Below is a sample how to do that starting from your code. You did not specify, if you want to create a new collection each time the display indices change, so in the following, I **reuse** the collection.

Please be aware, that the collection is now initialized from the `DataGrid` if your bound collection is either empty or does not have items for *all* columns, which would be prone to errors. The collection is initialized in the `Loaded` handler event, since the columns will have [`DisplayIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex?view=net-5.0) set to `-1` before the `DataGrid` is completely loaded.

> The DisplayIndex property has a default value of -1 before it is added to the DataGrid.Columns collection. This value is updated when the column is added to the DataGrid.

```
public class DataGridColumnChanger : DependencyObject
{
   #region dependency properties
   public static StringCollection GetColumnOrder(DependencyObject obj)
   {
      return (StringCollection)obj.GetValue(ColumnOrderProperty);
   }
   public static void SetColumnOrder(DependencyObject obj, StringCollection value)
   {
      obj.SetValue(ColumnOrderProperty, value);
   }
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnOrderProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnOrder",
      typeof(StringCollection), typeof(DataGridColumnChanger), new UIPropertyMetadata(new StringCollection(), OnColumnOrderChange));

   #endregion

   private static void OnColumnOrderChange(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      var dataGrid = (DataGrid)obj;

      if (e.NewValue == null)
      {
         // No collection set, unsubscribe from the event.
         dataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged -= OnDisplayIndexChanged;
      }
      else
      {
         // A new collection was set, subscribe to the event to sync it with user driven reordering.
         dataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += OnDisplayIndexChanged;

         var columnOrder = (StringCollection)e.NewValue;

         // The collection is not fully initialized.
         if (columnOrder == null || columnOrder.Count <= dataGrid.Columns.Count)
         {
            // Must be updated after load, otherwise the indices are -1.
            dataGrid.Loaded += OnDataGridLoaded;
            return;
         }

         try
         {
            for (var i = 0; i <= dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
               var index = Convert.ToInt32(columnOrder[i]);
               dataGrid.Columns[i].DisplayIndex = index;
            }
         }
         catch
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
         }
      }
   }

   private static void OnDataGridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
      var columnOrder = GetColumnOrder(dataGrid);

      // Since the collection is not fully initialized, clear it as it could be invalid.
      columnOrder.Clear();

      // Initialize the collection with the current column display indices.
      foreach (var column in dataGrid.Columns)
         columnOrder.Add(column.DisplayIndex.ToString());

      dataGrid.Loaded -= OnDataGridLoaded;
   }

   private static void OnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
   {
      var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
      var columnOrder = GetColumnOrder(dataGrid);
      var columnIndex = dataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(e.Column);

      // Sync the changed column display index.
      columnOrder[columnIndex] = e.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString();
   }
}
```

I also want to recommend you to use a collection of `int` instead of a `StringCollection`, because display indices are of type `int` and the conversions in the code are unnecessary then.

Goind forward, you might be interested in creating a [`Behavior<DataGrid>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki) instead of an attached property class, which is easier to write, as it already provides access to the associated object and other useful methods. For this, you can install the [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package.